# Reusing of Custom Cells

Tags: iphone, ios

I taken a custom cell  and i am not reusing the identifier over there. I am using the identifier in the table view where i am using that custom cells. But when i run my application and entering the data in textfield my data getting erased when i scroll the view.and My cell are not reusing that data.Can any one help me out in this thing. Thanks!

Custom cell code

```
-(UITableViewCell *)returnCellForEach:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];

        myLabel = (UILabel *)[customCell.contentView viewWithTag:10];

    return customCell;
}
```

Table view 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' code

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"Hello"] autorelease];
    }
```

whats mistake i this thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cells should not be used to store your data. If the user enters something in the edit field, you need to copy the content to e.g. a member variable in your view controller. If the cell is scrolled out of view, it is either destroyed, or it MIGHT be kept for reuse. Either way, you can not rely on that edit field to exist anymore.

Comment: i am not using cells to store data.I know cell wont store data.What my exat question is my table view contains 15cells.If i enter data in the first cell and if i go to last cell the data in the first cell is getting erased.In the sense the cells r not reusing the data.And the data in the first cell is getting erased.

Comment: That is what I mean. You expect that cell to remember its content, even if it is scrolled off screen. That will not work. The cell could get destroyed and rebuilt. You have to copy the content to a member variable. And fill it back in when asked to recreate that cell.

Comment: Ravi Kiran: dont assign values to labels at the time of creation of cells.

Comment: @Mahesh : I am working with database. I am entering the data in the text field and i need to show that data in the labels in the next view.i Can do that but i got more 15 cells in that each cell has one text field. so i need to scroll for the remaining text fields to enter the data. so if i scroll my data is destroying

Comment: @ Kris Van Bael : sorry i dint get u exactly. If u dont mind can u show me a sample code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I dont get your question actually, But I have done like following :

```
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = (CustomCell *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }

myLabel = (UILabel *)[customCell.contentView viewWithTag:10];
//myLabel = cell.labelWithTag10;
myLable.text = @"Text";
```

And It works fine for me;